# get list of followers for my X account using tweepy

Tags: tweepy, twitterapi-python, twitter-api-v2

I am using X API v2 (basic access) with Tweepy and want to get the list of my account followers.

Any idea how to achieve this please?

I know that  `client.get_users_followers(id)` is no more available for basic account users.
And I checked `User_fields=["connection_status"]` when performing tweet search which retutrns nothing.